# Is checking the location of the sign bit enough to determine endianness of IEEE-754 float with respect to integer endianness?

Tags: c++, floating-point, endianness, portability, ieee-754

I recently wrote some code that uses `memcpy` to unpack `float`/`double` to unsigned integers of the appropriate width, and then uses some bit-shifting to separate the sign bit from the combined significand/exponent.

> **Note:** For my use case, I don't need to separate the latter two parts from eachother, but I do need them in the correct order i.e: `{sign, (exponent, significand)}`, with the latter tuple packed as an unsigned int of sufficient width.

My code is working fine, thoroughly tested and no trouble; however I was a bit alarmed to discover that IEEE-754 doesn't specify the endianness of its binary interchange formats —which to my understanding, means there is a rare possibility that my bit-shifting may be incorrect in the rare occasions where *float endianness* ≠ *integer endianness*.

Based on the answered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763790/endianness-for-floating-point), my assumption is that given that bit-shifting is independent of actual endianness in storage, I only need to worry about whether the endianness of my floats matches that of my ints.
I devised the following code loosely following that in the linked answer, but avoiding the use of type-punning through pointer casts, which seems like unspecified/undefined behaviour territory to me:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>

// SAME means "same as integer endianness"
enum class FloatEndian { UNKNOWN, SAME, OPPOSITE, };

FloatEndian endianness() {
    float check = -0.0f; // in IEEE-754, this should be all-zero significand and exponent with sign=1
    std::uint32_t view;
    std::memcpy(&view, &check, sizeof(check));
    switch (view) {
    case 0x80000000: // sign bit is in most significant byte
        return FloatEndian::SAME;
    case 0x00000080: // sign bit is in least significant byte
        return FloatEndian::OPPOSITE;
    default: // can't detect endianness of float
        return FloatEndian::UNKNOWN;
    }
}
```

If I ensure that my floats are indeed IEEE-754 with `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`, is my approach a robust and portable way of making sure I get the floats "the right way round" when I chop them up?

Comment: I suppose we could even imagine a machine where floating-point numbers are *mixed* endian, where the sign bit is in (say) the least significant byte, but the other bytes are ordered in some other fashion.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes indeed, although (correct me if I'm wrong) if IEEE-754 format is guaranteed, then this possibility is excluded, as the ordering of the fields (sign, significand, exponent) _is_ specified **in relation to eachother** for that format, it's just the literal order of the bytes _all together_ that is unspecified.

Comment: At least `2301` ordering should be possible if not for `float` then for `int32`, e.g., if the machine only has native 16bit support. That said, I would not rely on any kind of runtime detection. Just provide a list of architectures where your code was tested and is known to work. If you have a CPU with weird byte ordering, there might be other quirks as well ...

Comment: @chtz why would you not rely on any runtime detection? (as an aside, I would prefer to do it at compile-time —this can be done if C++20's `bit_cast()` is used instead of memcpy, I've tested it on Godbolt.org but I don't have library support for it on the currently installed toolchain I have on my dev machine)

Comment: @NateEldredge The VAX-11 was one such real machine, possibly not in floating-point but certainly in 32-bit integers.

Comment: @saxbophone You are compiling for a specific CPU. It is therefore pointless *not* to handle this at compile time.

Comment: @saxbophone see [mixed endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian). The digits in `0123`, `3210`, `2301` means the byte number

Comment: @user207421 I would agree, except for the fact of whether the functions needed to work out the orientation of the floats with respect to int, can run at compile-time or not. For instance, if `bit_cast()` is not available due to lacking library/C++20 support, then one might have to use `memcpy()`, which I don't think is `constexpr`..?

Comment: @saxbophone "My code is ..., thoroughly tested ..." --> How ,many different platforms/compilers was it tested with?

Comment: Why not use macro `__BYTE_ORDER` just like GNU header `ieee754.h` does?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin As the endian of `float` and `uint32_t` may differ.  `__BYTE_ORDER__` is for integers.  `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` is for FP.  IAC, is is a GNU extension and not certainly available with other compilers.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica On what platform are byte orders of `float` and `uint32_t` different? Shouldn't you file a bug report against `ieee754.h` with a reproduction where `ieee754.h` is wrong?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin "what platform are byte orders of float and uint32_t different" is a good question to post. I have not, in last 10 yrs seen such and wonder too how common it remains - it certainly is rare.  [number of hardware architectures where floating-point numbers are represented in big-endian form while integers are represented in little-endian form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point). IAC, C does not require the same endian.  What specifically is the bug you are suggesting in ieee754.h?  That already supports different endian for integer/float.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You are right, `ieee754.h` uses `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER` for machines with different endianness for floating point values, my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is checking the location of the sign bit enough to determine endianness of IEEE-754 float with respect to integer endianness?

- As I read it, given the C++ spec and the C spec that it tends to also rely on,  checking the sign bit is technically insufficient to determine endian relationship between `float/uint32_t`.  It is likely practically sufficient as endians other than big/little are rare as well as differences between `float/uint32_t` endian.
- I would suggest a different constant than `-0.0f`, maybe `-0x1.ca8642p-113f` which has the pattern 0x87654321 and would be a more thorough endian test.  Quite unclear why OP wants to use a one's-bit-sparse `-0.0f` to discern 3 possible results.
- As mentioned by others, in C++, the test should be a compile time one, so thoroughness is not a run-time cost over the simplicity of only testing a sign bit.
- Relying on `is_iec559` is true may unnecessarily limits portability as for that to be true, many non-finite compliance rules are needed.  [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559).  Does your code really need quiet and signaling NANs?
- See also [If `is_iec559` is true, does that mean that I can extract exponent and mantissa in a well defined way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58308042/2410359).
- I hope OP also tests that the `sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)` else `memcpy(&view, &check, sizeof(check))` is bad code.

> is my approach a robust and portable way of making sure I get the floats "the right way round" when I chop them up?

- Code is not as robust and portable as it could be.
- "when I chop them up" --> that code is not shown, so unanswerable.
  I am suspect of the `endianness()` goal that is used to support "uses memcpy to unpack float/double to unsigned integers of the appropriate width, and then uses some bit-shifting to separate the sign bit from the combined significand/exponent."  It is that code that deserves review.

Comment: For the purposes of what I'm doing (a little bit of bit-hacking on IEEE-754's representation), I'm completely ok with requiring `is_iec559()` if it means I can guarantee (up to the point of a lying implementation of `std::numeric_limits` ;) ) that my floats are indeed IEEE-754. I only care that my code is portable among all systems that use IEEE-754 format.

Comment: @saxbophone 1) Since "only care that my code is portable" is the issue, not "Is checking the location of the sign bit enough", that code should be reviewed.  2) Requiring `is_iec559()` limits portability.

Comment: The point about the value being used for the endianness test is interesting. The reason why I decided to use `0.0f` is because the way I see it, if the float is in big-endian or little-endian format, I can split it apart into sign and combined exponent and significand, I only need to possibly flip the bytes if it's the other way round to that I expect it and then split off the sign. I assumed if it's neither of those ways round, there's no way for me to split off all the parts in a well-defined way, so I only have "SAME", "OPPOSITE" and "UNKNOWN". Is it possible to split in the latter case?

Comment: Do you think it would be worthwhile submitting the float-chopping, bit-shifting code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @saxbophone If the endian is not big nor little, `endianness()` may return `SAME` or `OPPOSITE`.  IOWs,  `endianness()` is a good test for big and little, but not a good test for other endians like PDP.

Comment: @saxbophone Yes, codereview is a goods place for code review, given that you reasonable believe it is error free.

Comment: Oh, I think I see it now —because say if it was some kind of middle-endian, it's possible that the sign bit might still get put into the first or last byte?

Comment: @saxbophone Yes, that what a more robust pattern than 0x80000000 provides.  IMO, consider the 3 known integer endians (big, little, PDP) and 2 known FP endians (big, little)  (e.g.  GCC `__BYTE_ORDER__`, `__FLOAT_WORD_ORDER__` and what those combinations could result in your test.  Yet I still think this dances around the issue as it is the unposted  float-chopping code itself that deserves review.  Possible a good solution for that may  not even need `endianness()`.

Comment: That is a really good point about the potential lack of need for the approach I'm using in the first place. I think my question might have hit the XY problem. Thank you for your forensic answer and follow-up, it is most helpful.